Trace theorem in $H^2(\Omega)$ and the affective restriction on the boundary
In Theorem 2.7.4 from Kesavan Topic in Functional Analysis 2003 says that there exists a map $\gamma = (\gamma_0, \gamma_1)$ from $H^2(\Omega)$ to $(L^2(\Omega))^2$ such that

If $v \in C^\infty(\overline {\Omega})$, then $\gamma_0(v) = v|_{\partial \Omega}$  and $\gamma_1 (v) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}|_{\partial \Omega}$.

I suspect it should be enough consider $v \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ in item (1) to obtain the same result, but I didn't find any reference with this. However, I wonder if it is enough just consider
$$v \in C^1_{\text{a.e.}}(\overline{\Omega}) := \{u : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R} : u \in C(\overline{\Omega}) \text{ and there exists } u_{x_i} \text{ a.e. in } \partial \Omega\}.$$
In other words, is the result still true if $v$ is continuously differentiable in $\overline{\Omega}$ except in a set of zero measure of the boundary? Is there any other result concern this?
Edit: What about if we assume $v \in H^2(\Omega) \cap C^1_{a.e.}(\overline{\Omega})$? In my case, if we denote $\mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$ and $x = (y,z)$, take $\varphi \in C^\infty_0((-1,1) \times (-1,1))$ and define $v(x) = \varphi(|y|, |z|)$. For large $n,m$, I know how to prove that $v \in H^2(B^1 \times B^2)$, where $B^1$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B^2$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$. I also know how to prove that $v = \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta} = 0$ in $\partial (B^1 \times B^2)$, expect in the sets $\{0\} \times \partial B^2$ and $\partial B^1 \times \{0\}$, where the first order derivatives are not defined. Remember
$$
\partial (B^1 \times B^2) = \partial B^1 \times \overline{B^2} \cup \overline{B^1} \times \partial B^2
$$ I would like to conclude that $v \in H^2_0(B^1 \times B^2)$ via trace theorem. In this case, can we say that $v$ has zero trace? Is it possible to conclude that $\gamma(v) = 0$ using other kind of arguments?

You are right that $v\in C^1(\overline\Omega)$ is enough. But it is dangerous to define $C^1_{a.e.}$ because it's not a Banach space. What is worse is that the almost everywhere structure is not topological.
The weakest assumption for $\gamma_0$ being bounded to $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is the fractional Sobolev space $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$. If you don't consider anisotropic derivatives then $\gamma:H^{3/2}(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)^2$ is "strongest result" of describing the boundedness. The book starts with $H^2$ in order to avoid discussion of fractional derivatives in the beginning.
But notice that $C^1\not\in H^2$ unless $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^1$. The whole point of $\gamma$ is to describe the fact that if smooth functions $v_j\xrightarrow{H^2}v$ (or $H^{3/2}$ if you want) then $\gamma(v_j)$ converges in the space $L^2(\partial\Omega)$. Hence we can describe $\gamma(v)$ as an abstract $L^2$ function on $\partial\Omega$, which only makes sense almost everywhere unless we impose further information on $v$. The function spaces are all that matters.
Update regarding the new questions in the post:
In your notation $H^2(\Omega)$ is enough to obtain $v_{x_i}$ on $\partial\Omega$. But so far it makes sense only as an $L^2$ function.
I also forget to mention that the meaning of a.e. exists is complicated. The standard one is formulated by the so-called nontangential maximal function see here. I know you want to use the classical limit of difference quotients. But this is not how it is used in every practice research.
In fact the $\gamma$ makes sense as long as $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain, where the surface measure (you can also use the $(n-1)$ dim Hausdorff measure) of $\partial\Omega$ is still a well-defined finite measure. In this case $\gamma_0:H^{1/2}(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is certainly well-defined. The normal vector field $\eta$ is still a $L^\infty$ vector field on $\partial\Omega$, so $\gamma_1(v)=\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_j\cdot\gamma_0(\partial_jf)$ is also well-defined as $H^{3/2}(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$.
Right $v\in H_0^2$ implies $\gamma(v)=0$, since $H_0^2$ is given by the closure of $C_c^\infty$ with respect to $H^2$ norm. The boundedness of $\gamma:H^2\to L^2$ implies that $\gamma(v)$ has to vanish.

Thank you Liding Yao for your answer. I just put and Edit with what I really need.

Answering the edited question, the part about the specific function.
What I am thinking is: the definition of the trace boils down to the fact that there is a linear estimate
$$ \|v|_{\partial\Omega}\|_{L^2}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1} $$
for smooth functions, which is extended by density to an operator defined on all $H^1$. This is a very abstract definition, but one can in principle make use of this and other estimates to prove other properties of the trace. For example, I claim that if $v$ is smooth in a neighbourhood of an open subset $V\subset\Omega$, then the trace of $v$ restricted to $V$ coincides almost everywhere with the restriction $v|_V$.
This claim proves that your function $v$ defined in terms of $\varphi$ is indeed in $H^2_0$, since $v$ is smooth in a neighbourhood of any open subset of the boundary, except maybe for a null set (although I don't see this problem with your function), so the trace coincides with the restriction of $v$ a.e. (and an analogous argument works for the first derivative of $v$).

Sketch of the proof of the claim.
Let $U\subset\Omega$ be a neighbourhood of $V$. Then, one has $V\subset\partial U$. In particular (if $U$ is nice enough, etc...) one has the estimate
$$ \|v|_{V}\|_{L^2}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1(U)} $$
for all functions that are smooth in $\overline U$. If in addition $v\in H^1(\Omega)$, one clearly has
$$ \|v|_{V}\|_{L^2}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}, $$
so the above extends to a linear bounded operator from $H^1(\Omega)$ to $L^2(V)$. Call it $T_V$.
Now, there is another very natural operator to consider: for any $v\in H^1(\Omega)$, take $\gamma$, the trace of $v$, and consider $\gamma|_V$. This also gives a linear bounded operator from $H^1(\Omega)$ to $L^2(V)$. Call it $S_V$.
Now, by their definition and the properties of the trace, it is clear that $T_V=S_V$ for any function $v$ which is in $C^\infty\cap H^1(\Omega)$. By density, $T_V=S_V$ for all $v$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. By focusing on functions $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ which are in addition smooth on $U$, this proves my claim.

You can see by yourself how to generalize the above proof to make it work in other more general settings you might need to consider ($v$ being continuous or $C^1$ around a neighbourhood of a subset of the boundary, etc...).

Thank you Lorenzo, your answer is very useful.
